# Custom object returns NSDictionary as type

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, object

my object **CCategory.h**

```
    @interface CCategory : NSObject

@property(strong, nonatomic) NSNumber * _Nonnull categoryId;
@property(strong, nonatomic) NSNumber * _Nonnull originalId;
@property(strong, nonatomic) NSString * _Nonnull name;
@property(strong, nonatomic) NSString * _Nonnull type;
@property(nonatomic, strong) CCategory * _Nullable  parent;
@property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) NSOrderedSet<CCategory *> *children;



- (instancetype _Nonnull )initWithId:(NSNumber *_Nullable)categoryId
               andOriginalId:(NSNumber *_Nullable)originalId
                   andName:(NSString *_Nonnull)name
                   andType:(NSString *_Nonnull)type
                   andParent:(CCategory *_Nullable)parent
                   andChildren:(NSOrderedSet<CCategory *> *_Nullable)children NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
@end
```

**CCategory.m**

```
@implementation CCategory


- (instancetype)init {
    return [self initWithId:0 andOriginalId:0 andName:@"" andType:@"" andParent:nil andChildren:nil];
}

- (instancetype)initWithId:(NSNumber *)categoryId
               andOriginalId:(NSNumber *)originalId
                   andName:(NSString *)name
                   andType:(NSString *)type
                    andParent:(CCategory *)parent
                   andChildren:(NSOrderedSet<CCategory *> *)children {

    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.categoryId = categoryId;
        self.originalId = originalId;
        self.name = name;
        self.type = type;
        self.parent = parent;
        self.children = children;

    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

This is how I check class type:

```
        CCategory * firstItem = [itemsArray objectAtIndex:0];

        CCategory *child = [firstItem.children objectAtIndex:0];

        NSString *className = NSStringFromClass([child class]);

        NSLog(@"First Item is: %@", className);
```

firstItem returns type `CCategory`, child returns type `NSDictionary`

After receiving from database object contains all data, but children for some reason is the `NSDictionary` type, not `CCategory` class type. Why is that? and how can I make children type `CCategory`?

Comment: How did you create `firstItem`? Because you declare it of some class doesn't mean that it's of the correct class. If you write for instance `NSArray *array = [@[@"Hello"] firstObject];`, `array` will be in fact a `NSString` object. In your `initWithId:...: andChildren:` method, check that each object inside the `NSOrderedSet` children parameter is really of class `CCategory`. That could help you point out where you didn't parse correctly maybe.

Comment: Yes you are right `Children` comes as `NSDictionary` type, for some reason I thought that `addChildren` method at `initWithId` converts `NSDictionary` type to `CCategory` automatically. Maybe there is a way to change `NSDictionary` type to `CCategory` when parsing or I need to change its type manually after parsing?

Comment: The questions is where does this code come from ? Where is `itemsArray` created or you data parsed. You said database, but you meant through a Web API, with JSON/XML ? Maybe giving the code of `initWithId:...: andChildren:` could help. Else, you can parse it inside the init, by creating yourself the Ordered Set, and call yourself `initWithId:...: andChildren:` with children at (nil, if there are no children).

Comment: It comes from Firebase

Comment: and items in `itemsArray` is of type `CCategory` but its nested children is of type `NSDirectory`

Comment: Like, in `initWithId:...`: `NSMutableOrderedSet *childrenSet = [[NSMutableOrderedSet alloc] init]; for (NSDictionary *aChildDict in [children array]){ CCategory *aChild = [CCategory alloc] initWithId:aChildDict[keyWhereThereIsID], etc.], [childrenSet addObject:aChild];} self.children = childrenSet;`

Comment: write it as an answer I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you declare some object of some class doesn't mean that it's of the correct class. 
If you write for instance

```
NSArray *array = [@[@"Hello"] firstObject];
```

`array` will be in fact a `NSString` object.

So, when you parse your response and create your `CCategory` object from what I guess a `NSDictionary` object.
That's why `children` seems to be in fact an `NSOrderedSet` of `NSDictionary` and not of `CCategory` objects.

A possible way to do it, is to call recursively `initWithId:andOriginalId:andName:andType:andParent:andChildren:` for the children.

So instead of  `self.children = children;`

```
NSMutableOrderedSet *childrenSet = [[NSMutableOrderedSet alloc] init]; 
for (NSDictionary *aChildDict in [children array])
{
    CCategory *aChild = [CCategory alloc] initWithId:aChildDict[keyWhereThereIsID], etc.] 
    [childrenSet addObject:aChild];
}
self.children = childrenSet;
```

But that's more of a hack to set it like that in the `init` method, because it says `children` should be `NSOrderedSet<CCategory *> *`.

So it's up to you, to either rename the method to be clear of what it does and maybe accept a `NSOrderedSet<NSDictionary *> *` for `children` instead, parse it before, create another one, etc.

One possible lazy option is to do that:

Rename to `andChildren:(NSOrderedSet *)children`

```
NSMutableOrderedSet *childrenSet = [[NSMutableOrderedSet alloc] init]; 
for (id *aChildObject in [children array])
{
    CCategory *aChild = nil;
    if ([aChildObject isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) //Need parsing
    {
        NSDictionary *aChildDict = (NSDictionary *)aChildObject;
        aChild = [CCategory alloc] initWithId:aChildDict[keyWhereThereIsID], etc.];
    }
    else if ([aChildObject isKindOfClass:[CCategory class]]) //Already a CCategory Object
    {
        aChild = (CCategory  *)aChildObject;
    }
    else 
    {
        NSLog(@"Ooops, child of wrong class: %@", NSStringFromClass([aChildObject class]);
    }

    if (aChild) { [childrenSet addObject:aChild]; }
}
self.children = childrenSet;
```

Comment: Helped me a lot!